# Software Request Plasmoid For Kubuntu 18.04 to control CPU Frequency

Tags: kubuntu, cpufreq, plasma-5

There are many neer duplicates of this question but I recommend deleting ones that are not version specific (ie 18.04) as we cannot know if a solution will be viable on future versions.

This is the case here, unfortunately.

The requirements to answer this question:

(1) works on 18.04 & runs as a plasmoid in the panel
Or
(2) works in 18:04 & runs in the panel as notification or other

to scale CPU frequency.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best place to make a software request. I found "You can submit feature requests at https://bugs.kde.org by selecting "Severity: wishlist" when submitting a bug." from https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/68rg5a/is_there_a_dedicated_page_for_feature_requests/ . I suggest you read that reddit page fully.

Comment: It's not a software request as in a request for someone to make something.  It is a request for known software.

Comment: Okay, I just looked at "Get new widgets" (after clicking on ☰ in the taskbar and then on *Add new widgets*) and didn't come across anything related to manipulating CPU frequency via a plasmoid. I had also searched the 'net before posting my comment.

Comment: If what I were looking for were there, would I have come here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this which I just created?

https://github.com/jsalatas/plasma-pstate

Comment: Hi, can you please help out [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1164100/248158)?