# KDE pager widget change size

Tags: kde

I'm usually using 4 virtual desktops and I like to keep the *pager widget* in the taskbar, which shows which desktop I'm currently looking at.

But the widget is relatively large:

[image]

Is there a way to decrease the width of the desktop symbols in the pager widget?

My plasmashell version is 5.12.8.

Comment: There may be a way. See, for example, https://askubuntu.com/q/1094113/248158 and [this link](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/74742-Where-to-ask-plasmoid-code-manipulation-questions?p=422977#post422977).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found the correct line in the main.qml file yet but this looks really promising!

Comment: More reading here: https://zren.github.io/kde/docs/widget/

Comment: Thanks again! I'll have a look. I updated the question to reflect my progress on this. But this might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure? I usually don't look at questions that already have an answer (I'm more active on a different site of StackExchange) that's why I thought it would make more sense to include it in the question for now until I have a proper answer.

Comment: @DKBose I solved it! Finally found the line I needed to change :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out with massive help from @DKBose!

Here are the steps

#### 1. make backup of config file

```
sudo cp /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml_backup
```

#### 2. edit config using favourite editor (I simply use `kate`)

```
kate /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml
```

#### 3. Change the width of each desktop symbol (I simply add `/ 2` at the end of the line to get half the original width):

```
property int columnWidth: Math.floor(rowHeight * pagerItemSizeRatio) / 2
```

#### 4. Change the minimum width of the whole widget (again just adding `/ 2`, this time after `aspectRatio`):

```
Layout.minimumWidth: !root.vertical ? Math.floor(height * aspectRatio / 2) : 1
```

And here is the result:

[image]

#### (5.) In case anything goes wrong just copy the backup file back into location:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml_backup /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.pager/contents/ui/main.qml
```

Comment: I did this, but made the applet twice as wide instead of half.  I found I also needed to double the `Layout.maximumWidth` to prevent the pager applet from overlapping the applet to its right.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped

Comment: I found when I connect the second monitor it takes the total width of both monitors in calculations (therefore the virtual desktops icons become x2 wider). So I had to change `/ 2` to `/ 4`. However now if I disconnect the second monitor the icons on the remaining monitor resize and become too narrow. Is there a way to make that `2 / 4` coefficient dependent on the number of monitors being used? Automatically?

Comment: I usually position my monitors on top of each other, so I never noticed. Maybe worth asking this as a question?

Comment: I also tested this widget and really like it so far: https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/virtual-desktop-bar Maybe I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Just open systemsettings and choose "Desktop Behavior" -> "Virtual Desktops" and make it two Rows. The widget will adjust to half width and the four desktops will be shown in two rows as shown in the screenshot (it seems a little bit wide because I have 3 monitors).

You don't really need to modify the code. :)

[image: KDE Virtual Desktops]

Comment: Thanks! You are right that the widget gets much smaller and I like how simple it is. But it changes the arrangement of the desktops which I don't like.